# Error: unable to unlink old, when trying to get changes from Git

Tags: git

I am trying to get a few changes added to the git repository, but I still get the following error:

```
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 1ea49ef..1e423fb
error: unable to unlink old 'app/templates/projects/project_2.html' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'app/templates/projects/project_5.html' (Permission denied)
```

I tried to find answers on the forum and apply a solution like `sudo chmod -R ug+w .` but that did not fix my mistake.

How can I download my changes from the Git repository?

Comment: Maybe try to do a manual cleanup of the files leading to the problems using `rm -f` (of course make sure that the files are not needed). There might be some filesystem issues...

Comment: `Permission denied` => check the permissions on those files. My bet: you have cloned/check out this repo as root and you are now a normal user.

Comment: Post the output of the following commands: `stat app/templates/projects/project_2.html`, `stat app/templates/projects`, `stat app`, `stat .`, `groups`

Comment: Zeitounator - thank you! when I became root again, everything was successfully downloaded.